# Why is input offset current halved?

Tags: current, offset

I am reading a data sheet that has offset current at 200nA, however, some calculations are using the total offset current.

**Why does the op-amp image below half the Offset current?**

[Datasheet](https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/fdscontent/uscompanion/us/pdf/microcircuits/students/amps/ua741philip.pdf)

[image]

Comment: You should post the relevant datasheet link and refer to specific parts of the datasheet.

Comment: It is more a general question about calculations when using offset current rather than a datasheet question.

Comment: I don't see this "halving" of which you speak. What calculations exactly are you referring to.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a mistake.

Ibias = (Ibp+Ibn)/2

Ios = Ibp - Ibn

Where Ibp is the current flowing into the non-inverting input and Ibn is the current flowing into the inverting input.